# Get the row with max(timestamp)

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I need to select most recently commented articles, with the last comment for each article, i.e. other columns of the row which contains `max(c.created)`:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.text, max(c.created) AS cid, c.text?
FROM subscriptions s
JOIN articles a ON a.id=s.article_id
JOIN comments c ON c.article_id=a.id
WHERE s.user_id=%d
GROUP BY a.id, a.title, a.text
ORDER BY max(c.created) DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Postgres tells me that I have to put c.text into GROUP BY. Obviously, I don't want to do this. min/max doesn't fit too. I don't have idea, how to select this.

Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL, [**`DISTINCT ON`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) is probably the optimal solution for this kind of query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.id)
       a.id, a.title, a.text, c.created, c.text
FROM   subscriptions s
JOIN   articles      a ON a.id = s.article_id
JOIN   comments      c ON c.article_id = a.id
WHERE  s.user_id = %d
ORDER  BY a.id, c.created DESC
```

This retrieve articles with the latest comment and associated additional columns.
Explanation, links and a benchmark in this [closely related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860).

To get the latest 10, wrap this in a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.id)
             a.id, a.title, a.text, c.created, c.text
    FROM   subscriptions s
    JOIN   articles      a ON a.id = s.article_id
    JOIN   comments      c ON c.article_id = a.id
    WHERE  s.user_id = 12
    ORDER  BY a.id, c.created DESC
    ) x
ORDER  BY created DESC
LIMIT  10;
```

Alternatively, you could use [**window functions**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) in combination with standard **`DISTINCT`**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       a.id, a.title, a.text, c.created, c.text
      ,first_value(c.created) OVER w AS c_created
      ,first_value(c.text)    OVER w AS c_text
FROM   subscriptions s
JOIN   articles      a ON a.id = s.article_id
JOIN   comments      c ON c.article_id = a.id
WHERE  s.user_id = 12
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY c.article_id ORDER BY c.created DESC)
ORDER  BY c_created DESC
LIMIT  10;
```

This works, because `DISTINCT` (unlike aggregate functions) is applied `after` window functions.
You'd have to test which is faster. I'd guess the last one is slower.